# Using JButton ActionListener to run different class in same package

Tags: java, user-interface, constructor, jbutton, getter-setter

I'm having an issue as I'm relatively new to **GUI**.

Basically to put everyone in the picture, I have a package which consists of:

- my `MainClass` (Includes the GUI)
- A seperate Class (Don't want it to run unless button is clicked)
- Another seperate class which I don't want to run unless it's specific button is clicked.

So my `MainClass` GUI is basically the controller.

However, I honestly have no clue how to go about it. Was told to have to create a **constructor** and use getters/setters? However I still don't understand how to call that specific class whilst leaving the other off **"Turned off"**.

Thanks.

Comment: can you explain what other classes do .. are they GUI or will they perform a particular task

Comment: The other classes perform a particular task, no GUI is set on the other classes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, there are quite a few ways to do this... Either you create anonymous listeners for each button, and then, depending on what you want to do, trigger methods in other classes or the like;

```
JButton b1 = new JButton();
b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        //Do something!
        OtherClass other = new OtherClass();
        other.myMethod();
    }
});

JButton b2 = new JButton();
b2.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        //Do something else!
        ...
    }
});
```

Alternatively, you use the command string and associate a unique command (made final, preferably) which you compare with when receiving a actionPerformed in a common listener implementation;

```
//In your class, somewhere...
public final static String CMD_PRESSED_B1 = "CMD_PRESSED_B1";
public final static String CMD_PRESSED_B2 = "CMD_PRESSED_B2";

//Create buttons
JButton b1 = new JButton();
JButton b2 = new JButton();

//Assign listeners, in this case "this", but it could be any instance implementing ActionListener, since the CMDs above are declared public static
b1.addActionListener(this);
b2.addActionListener(this);

//Assign the unique commands...
b1.setActionCommand(CMD_PRESSED_B1);
b2.setActionCommand(CMD_PRESSED_B2);
```

And then, in your listener implementation;

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    if (e.getActionCommand().equals(CMD_PRESSED_B1)
    {
        //Do something!
        OtherClass other = new OtherClass();
        other.myMethod();
    }

    else if (e.getActionCommand().equals(CMD_PRESSED_B2)
    {
        //Do something else!
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot Markus, the syntax works just need to write the correct method

Comment: Happy to hear. Please mark answer as accepted if you feel that you got the answer you needed.